# How can I add a custom Object in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, xcode4, nsobject

I'm using XCode4 and using the awesome TTTAttributedLabel class. I've created an NSObject and set its class to TTTAttributedLabel. I can't seem to add this to my View. How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your class subclasses a standard control, then you can edit the class in the right panel. Here's how you'd change the class of a UILabel:

[image]

Other than that, Xcode 4 dropped support for IB plugins.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the screenshot too it speaks a thousand words.

Comment: I did the same but I'm getting "Unknown class TTTAttributedLabel in Interface Builder file"